# Unable to convert current time to a specific date format ending with Z

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert current time to a specific format but I can't make it. This is what I'm trying to produce `2021-05-02T18:00:00.000Z`. However, `2021-05-04T00:21:25.199218` is what the following script produces.

```
import datetime

date_ = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
print(date_)
```

> How can I achieve that format?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that with datetime. Try using pytz instead. It includes the Zulu timezone.

Comment: please make this a comment. and no, you don't need pytz here.

Comment: Sadly I can't comment yet. And I think you do need pytz. Got a better answer?

Comment: you'll have the needed reputation points soon ;-)

Comment: Hopefully. String replacement. I thought of that too. What if it isn't +00:00? Like this, 2021-05-04T00:21:25.199218?

Comment: btw, pytz is for handling time zones, for which you have [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) with Python 3.9 - but here this is not needed since the OP only needs UTC which is handled by datetime.timezone.utc

Comment: if it's not +00:00, it's not UTC, i.e. Z would be wrong

Comment: Oh, that's true. I think he's trying to convert to a non-UTC timezone though? I'll just wait for a response.

Comment: you can use `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec="milliseconds").replace("+00:00", "Z")
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Datetime is naively not aware of timezones. But having a time print out like includes timezone info 'Z'. So you have ask for a timezone specifically: `dt = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)`
2. Python uses whatever time microseconds resolution. `datetime.isoformat` will by default use whatever resolutions is available. However you are only interested in miliseconds, so you have to specify that explicitly: `iso_ts = dt.isoformat(timespec="milliseconds")`
3. Unfortunately, the isoformat will always use the UTC offset as suffix. If you really need 'Z' to indicate offset +00:00 you will need to change that manually: `iso_ts.replace("+00:00", "Z")`. While replace might look dangerous here, remember that 'Z' always means +00:00 offset. Theoretically -00:00 is also possible (not sure of the exact spec), but python will never generate it. And if you got other offset, then it couldn't be 'Z'.

This gives you `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec="milliseconds").replace("+00:00", "Z")`.

Comment: Okay, it appears to be working. What if the date to be converted is `1980-01-22`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This should work for any date, as long as you can create a `datetime` object with timezone info